# Weyl's unitarian trick on real vector spaces

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Weyl's unitarian trick for a compact (matrix) Lie group $G$, for which one can define a Haar measure, states that [Knapp, Proposition 4.6]

> *If $\Phi$ is a representation of $G$ on a finite-dimensional (vector space) $V$, then $V$ admits a [Hermitian inner product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html) such that $\Phi$ is unitary.*

In this proposition, I think Knapp implicitly assumes that $V$ is defined over $\mathbb{C}$ (hence the usage of a *Hermitian* inner product). But a few pages later (Proposition 4.24), he applies this trick to the *adjoint representation* $Ad$ of $G$, which acts on a *real* vector space (the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$), to show that one can define a [*real* inner product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html) on $\mathfrak{g}$ so that $Ad$ is *orthogonal* (not *unitary*) on $\mathfrak{g}$, and the associated $ad$ for $\mathfrak{g}$ is anti-*symmetric* (not anti-*Hermitian*).

In the book [Knapp] does not give a detailed explanation of the Haar measure of compact groups, so I want to ask whether the unitarian trick can be applied to representations acting on a *real* vector space (or vector spaces defined over more general fields other than $\mathbb{C}$).

---

[Knapp]: Anthony W. Knapp, *Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction* (1996)

Comment: Yes, it works exactly the same in the real case.

Comment: This is not what I would call the "unitary trick", it is just the statement that any representation of a compact Lie group is unitary. In my understanding, the unitary trick is relating complex representations of a complex semisimple Lie group to complex representations of its compact real form.